# how to get information from Azure DevOps using powershell script and show to power BI service?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powerbi

There might be some methods to get access to RESTful APIs from my research. 
Httpclient? using id and password might be not secure.
What is the way to get access to Azure Devops with a personal token?
any example code? 
the code below is what I have tried and it showed credential failed.

thank you.

powershell code

```
 function InputToPowerBI {
  param ([string]$type,[string]$title,[string]$assignedTo,[string]$state)
$endpoint =  "address of the end point"
$payload = @{
"Type" =$type
"Title" =$title
"Assigned To" =$assignedTo
"State" =$state
"Area Path" =$areaPath
"Tags" =$tag
"Comment Count" =$commentCount
}

$json = ConvertTo-Json @($payload);

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body $json
}

GetData;



function GetData
{
    try
    {
        $personalAccessToken="Personal token such as eiejr22837482";
        $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
        $header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
        $projectsUrl = "address of the current sprint from Azure DevOps"

        $projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
        $projects.value | ForEach-Object {

}
    }
    catch
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: Check here for some example code: https://powershell.org/2019/04/azure-devops-enable-allow-scripts-to-access-the-oauth-token-using-powershell/

Comment: It seems that it's wrong while you call variable "personAccessToken" in GetBytes("xxxxx"), correct it as GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"). Could you provide more message about "credential failed"?  Does the code written by the ps1 file or in the inline of powershell task?